# Nobody can stop me. Who Am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Just enter the ring 
Offer yourself
Holds never barred
Nobody can stop me
Contain your enthusiasm 
Everyone gets a shot
Nationally renowned
At the first of each line 

And his name is?

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is called a pseudoriddle. Are you using that term in the same sense as the footnote in this link? https://books.google.com/books?id=-N0JCxuKv9EC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145

Comment: @Ben It is indeed sort of like that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

His name is of course

> JOHN CENA!

The lines

> Are about the fact that he is a wrestler, but the last line refers to the fact that the first letters of each line form his name